# Is there a way to only publish changed submodules when publishing locally using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a library repo with many subprojects. Some take longer to publish locally than others due to compilation times. Is there any way to configure `publishLocal` to only re-publish ones that have changed since last `publishLocal`?

I haven't found any options that allow me to configure this.

Comment: You could do it manually: only publish the ones that you know have changed. Interactively, this can be done with `sbt`, `project xxx`, `publishLocal` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

As @GaëlJ had mentioned, another manual approach could be done like so:

```
sbt your_updated_subproject/publishLocal
```

This ensures you publish the latest changes of your updated subproject without having to publish all subprojects.